# wrapping angular2 material md-button inside a custom button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying the wrap a material md-button inside a custom-button and passing along the the type of button I want to render via an attribute. The attribute gets passed along but too late in the rendering pipeline most likely as the material styles are being applied.

```
@Component({
     selector: 'custom-button',
     template: `
          <button
              [attr.md-raised-button]="isRaisedButton()">
              <ng-content></ng-content>
          </button>`,
     directives: [MD_BUTTON_DIRECTIVES]
 })
export class CustomButton {
    @Input('raised-button') public raisedButton: boolean = null;
    public isRaisedButton(): string {
        return (this.raisedButton != null && this.raisedButton != false) ? '' : null;
    }
}
```

My is then used like this.

```
  <custom-button raised-button>button text</custom-button>
```

As I said the attributes gets added properly but the button is not rendered as a material raised input.

Any help is appreciated.